# Windows IOT Local Database Hosting

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

**What am I trying to do:**
I want to deploy a Windows IoT (Universal Windows) app on multiple Raspberry Pi3 devices. This app will READ data from a database. The database must be on a local network (no internet access). The database will be hosted on a Windows 10 machine or another RPi3.

Here is where I am stuck. I want to be able to connect these devices, via C# code, to a database hosted on a local machine on the closed network. The thing is SQLite cannot do this task, since it is embedded. Any other options that can help?

Answer (score 2):

If you have any regular (x86/x64) machine you can run any database on that (sql server, MySQL etc).

I don't know whether you are using .Net Core or UWP for your app on the raspberry devices?

In .Net Core you can use [something from here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/), that might also work for UWP.

I don't know about databases that can run on Windows IoT Core, maybe you could find an answer on google for that.